# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list : Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, sorting

I was trying to **bubble sort** the temperature array but i am getting this kind of error.. Someone please help me fix this :)

Here's the code :

```
print("")
print("")

days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thrusday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
temperature = []
highest = float(0.0)
lowest = float(100.0)
total = float(0.0)  

for i in range(7):
    inp = round(float(input("Please enter the temperature for " + days[i] + " in Celcus: ")),1)
    temperature.append(inp)
    


print("")
print("")
    
print("You entered these Temperatures in Celsius and Fahrenheit.")

print("")
print("")


for j in range(len(temperature)):
    
    def bubble_sort(tem):
        for a in range(len(tem)):
            for b in range(len(tem)-1):
                if(tem[b]>tem[b+1]):
                    temp=tem[b]
                    tem[b]=tem[b+1]
                    tem[b+1]=temp
        return tem
    arr = []
    arr.append(temperature[j])
    Fahrenheit = round(((temperature[j] * 1.8) + 32),1)
    total = total + temperature[j]
    print(bubble_sort(arr) + " C° is " + str(Fahrenheit) + " F°" )
    
print("--------------------")
avg = round(total / len(temperature),1)
print("High Temp: " + str(max(temperature)) + "C°, Low Temp: " + str(min(temperature)) + " C° Average Temp: " + str(avg) + " C°")
```

I am not getting what wrong is with this code ..

Comment: what line does raise the error ?

Comment: Please show the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: you are appending to a list in two locations. Which one is throwing the error?

Comment: Side-note: Python can avoid a temp variable in the `bubble_sort` swap step, replacing the entire contents of the `if` block with just `tem[b], tem[b+1] = tem[b+1], tem[b]`. Or if you're feeling clever/tricky, you can do `tem[b+1], tem[b] = tem[b:b+2]` or even `tem[b:b+2] = tem[b+1:b-1:-1]` to reduce the number of indexing operations down to a smaller number of slicing operations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the defectiv line is

```
print(bubble_sort(arr) + " C° is " + str(Fahrenheit) + " F°" )
```

since you are using the "+" operator on a list and a string
in order to fix it try converting the list (that you get from calling "bubble_sort(arr)" to a string  )

like this

```
print(''.join(str(e) for e in bubble_sort(arr)) + " C° is " + str(Fahrenheit) + " F°")
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty explicit: the `list` is `bubble_sort(arr)` and the `str` is `" C° is "`

You can't concatenate them at `bubble_sort(arr) + " C° is "`, you'd need to wrap the list into `str`

---

The nicest is just to use the fact that `print` allows multiple values to be given

```
print(bubble_sort(arr), "C° is", Fahrenheit, "F°")

print("High Temp:", max(temperature), "C°, Low Temp:",
      min(temperature), "C° Average Temp:", avg, "C°")
```

---

Now, you're not **sorting anything** as there is only ONE value in `arr`, just sort once before the loop, then show the Fahrenheit  value

```
arr = bubble_sort(temperature)
for value in arr:
    fahrenheit = round(((value * 1.8) + 32), 1)
    print(value, "C° is", fahrenheit, "F°")

avg = round(sum(temperature) / len(temperature), 1)
print("High Temp:", max(temperature), "C°, Low Temp:",
      min(temperature), "C° Average Temp:", avg, "C°")
```

Comment: Some of the leading and trailing spaces in the `print`s can be removed (since `sep=' '` is the default, and it adds the spaces the literals used to have to include manually). f-strings are also an option (for when you want the concatenated string for some reason, not just for `print`ing, though it works just fine for `print`ing too; in this case, I'd probably avoid it if only to avoid shoving too much computation into the f-string). Advantage to the f-strings is they could handle the rounding implicitly, removing explicit pre-rounding with `round`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Hope these advice aren't for me haha I got that. I think, the exact space input if not at all what is expected here regarding the quality of the input code, which has non-sense lines

Comment: The advice is a *little* for you; if you're replacing concats with comma separated `print` arguments, you should remove the spaces to get the same output spacing as the OP's code. But yeah, I assume you're aware of this.